custom image for splash screen in compose
I am using the splash screen and want to have an image instead of a background color.
This is a compose project.
androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1

I am using the following
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.BusbyNimbleSurvey</item>
    </style>
</resources>

the splash is a png image and I have also tried with a webp. However, when testing it just a black background.
Is this possible?

Please also show us the Compose code where you use the splash screen.

According to the documentation of SplashScreen API it's not possible. Use windowSplashScreenBackground to fill the background with a specific single color

Can you please put the image or video that gives a better understanding of your problem

I have tried several ways while finding to set drawable as a Splash Screen Background but failed.
While digging into SDK code, I found this in values.xml that only color values can be set as background in Splash Screen API.
Attached screenshot is for the reference.

